# change background color of selected button with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am creating a quiz and want to change color of button selected by user.

```
var start = true;

if (start) {
    begin(0);
}

function begin(id) {

    // placing questions
    const question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerText = Questions[id].q;

    // placing options
    document.getElementById('op1').innerText = Questions[id].a[0].text;
    document.getElementById('op2').innerText = Questions[id].a[1].text;
    document.getElementById('op3').innerText = Questions[id].a[2].text;
    document.getElementById('op4').innerText = Questions[id].a[3].text;

    $(".btn").click(function () {

        var selected = $(this).attr("id");
        selected.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
    );

}
```

Questions contains questions with options in json format.
The color of selected button is not changing, I am really new to JavaScript, someone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use jQuery object `$(this)`, `$(this).css('background-color','red');` to change button color when click.

Or get id via `document.getElementById("Your-button-id")`.

*Note: Please avoid mismatch jQuer and JavaScript*

Examples:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="quiz" class='btn' id='btn' />
```

Or:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  let selected = document.getElementById("btn");
  selected.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="quiz" class='btn' id='btn' />
```

Comment: Thank you, its working now. Can you explain the problem in my code?

Comment: "Note: Please avoid mismatch `jQuer` and `JavaScript`".   explain ever thing.  Your selector of id is mismatched.